# Cannot create new Instance Properties in Vue.js (laravel project)

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, laravel-8

I'm trying to create localization property, like `__('text')` in Laravel blade template.
I have created a global window variable, which contents all needed data with name `window.i18n`

Here is my `resourses/js/app.js` file:

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

// Here I tried to create new Instance properties
import _ from 'lodash'
window.Vue.prototype.__ = str => _.get(window.i18n, str)

Vue.component('autocomplete',require('./components/SearchComponent.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

And my `/components/SearchComponent.vue` file, only script part:

```
<script>
 export default{
    props: [
        'categories'
    ],
    data(){
        return {
            query: '',
            results: [],
            categoryText: __('text.save'), // Here I tried to use __() property
            categoryId: 0
        }
    },
    methods: {
    autoComplete() {
        this.results = [];
        if(this.query.length > 2){
            axios.get('/posts/search',{params: {query: this.query, category_id: this.categoryId}}).then(response => {
                this.results = response.data;
                this.categoryText = "Избери";
                this.categoryId = 0;
            });
        }
    },
    categoryChange(e) {
        this.categoryText = e.target.text;
        var id = event.target.getAttribute('data-category-id');
        this.categoryId = id;
    },
    mounted: function () {
        console.log(this.categories);
    }
    }
 }
</script>
```

I got this error:

> app.js:38639 [Vue warn]: Error in data(): "ReferenceError: __ is not
> defined"

Cannot handle what I'm missing.

Comment: did you try window.__('text.save') ?

Comment: @MehediHassan I can get it with `window.i18n.text.save` but the idea is to use something like `__('text.save')` like blade template

Comment: Did you try use categoryText as computed property? `return this.__(‘text.save’)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've added the `__` to `Vue.prototype`, which makes it an instance property. To access instance properties, use `this` inside `data()`:

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {         
      categoryText: this.__('text.save')
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you could make `__` a global by attaching it directly to `window`, which would allow your current code to work:

```js
window.__ = str => _.get(window.i18n, str)
```

Comment: You should be aware that this solution is not reactive: switching languages won't automatically update `categoryText`. Use `vue-i18n` instead, and move `categoryText` into `computed`.